# Shader node link connector invisible blender 2.82

Tags: modeling, modifiers, node-editor, shaders

I downloaded **Blender 2.82** its good, but my problem is that the shader node link is invisible while dragging to connect another node. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. 
I updated the driver of my graphic card (AMD Radeon™ HD 8750M) and now is all good, i can see the node connector.
Hope it helps.